# two strange lines when hover

Tags: html, css

When I mouse over on a pure html/css site here:
https://unruffled-shaw-39b759.netlify.app/

CSS is in this link - https://unruffled-shaw-39b759.netlify.app/css/style.css

I have two strange lines as below

[image]

How to get rid of it?

Comment: Why can't I have option of `View Page Source` on your website while it is available on every other site . Also don't provide external links, instead paste the code here(`html` `CSS`)

Comment: Please add the necessary code to the question rather than links to an external page that may disappear in time and render the question obsolete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of skew and then de-skew probably.

You can fix it by adding: `overflow: hidden;` for `story__shape`

Add this:

```
.story__shape {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Wow that's work, can you explain further why `overflow: hidden` could help?

Comment: @william007 it's just how it happens currently, when we skew a container and then skew the image in it in the opposite direction, it causes distortion at the edges.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `backface-visibility: hidden;` from

```
.story__img {
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-4rem) scale(1.4);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

This will work.